# Recuar um bloco de código no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentação

Qual é a tecla de atalho usada para recuar um bloco inteiro de código no Visual Studio Code, para fazer a indentação?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se quiser um "efeito" de `tab` invertido: `Shift + tab`

De uma olhada na documentação de atalhos do [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings).

Answer (score 6):

Selecione o bloco de codigo que você deseja recuar e aperte a tecla `Shift` e a tecla `Tab` juntas, ou para apenas dar um espaço no codigo selecione tudo e aperte `Tab`